# The ladder of the real closure of an ordered field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, model-theory, ordered-fields

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lad}{Lad}$Let $(K,<)$ be an ordered field, and $(R,<)$ be the real closure of $(K,<)$. Let $\lad(K)$ denote the ladder of $(K,<)$ (for the definition of the ladder, see the link given below). Then the canonical injection $\iota \colon \lad(K) \to \lad(R)$ is induced. My first question is the following.

**Question 1**. Is $\iota \colon \lad(K) \to \lad(R)$ an isomorphism?

I came up with this question when I read https://mathoverflow.net/a/23529/131576. According to the answer, Question 1 is true in the following case.

**Proposition**. Let $L$ be a linear order. Write $F = \bar{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $(K,<)$ be the ordered field $F(x_l : l \in L)$ as in the answer. Then $\iota$ is an isomorphism.

In fact, $(R,<)$ is contained in the field of Hahn series $F[[t^G]]$, where $G$ is the group $\mathbb{Q}^{{\oplus} L}$ with a suitable order. However, this proof seems a little bit hard in that it uses Hahn series. Then my second question is the following.

**Question 2**. Are there any easier proofs of the Proposition?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easy proof of $1$, but there is a somewhat elementary one using valuation theory and more specifically the natural valuation on an ordered field. The idea is that the value group of $R$ is the divisible hull of that of $K$, but here I only prove what's necessary for your result.

So let $v$ denote the generic function of natural valuation on an ordered field, and let $\operatorname{Lad}$ denote the generic function of comparability class on an ordered field. Notice that if $K$ is an ordered field and $x \in K$ is positive infinite, then $\operatorname{Lad}(y)=\operatorname{Lad}(x)$ for all $y \in v x$.
(in fact, the Ladder functor is naturally isomorphic to the composition of the natural valuations functors on the categories of ordered fields and ordered groups).

**Claim:** if $A$ is an algebraic (ordered field) extension of $K$ and $x \in A$, we have $d_x:=[v K[x]: v K] <\infty$.

It is no secret that $R$ is an algebraic extension of $A$ so we may apply the claim. Let $x \in R^{\times}$ be positive infinite. We have $d_x.vK[x] \subseteq v K$ so $d_x. v x =v x^{d_x}=v y$ for some element $y \in K^{\times}$ which must be infinite. We have $\operatorname{Lad}(x)=\operatorname{Lad}(x^{d_x})=\operatorname{Lad}(y) \in \operatorname{Lad}(K)$, hence $\operatorname{Lad}(R)=\operatorname{Lad}(K)$.

---

**Proof of the claim:** notice that every finite family $(\gamma_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ in $\Gamma_{K[x]}$ such that for $i\neq j$ we have $\gamma_i - \gamma_j \notin \Gamma_K$, and for $x_1,...,x_n \in K[x]^{\times}$ with $\forall 1 \leq i \leq n,\gamma_i= v x_i$, the family $(x_1,...,x_n)$ is free in the $K$-vector space $K[x]$. Indeed for $(0,...,0)\neq (a_1,...,a_n) \in K^n$ and $1\leq i \neq j  \leq n$, we have $\gamma_j - \gamma_i\notin v K \ni v a_i - v a_j$ so $v a_i x_i =v a_i + \gamma_i\neq v a_j + \gamma_j =v a_j x_j$. By standard properties of valuations, we have $v \sum \limits_{i=1}^n a_i x_i=\min_{i=1}^n v a_i x_i$, and in particular the element $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n a_i x_i$ is non zero. The extension $K[x] / K$ is finite, so $[v K[x]: vK]$ must be finite.

---